# How to display two grouped products in one product page in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have to create a grouped product page in magento in which a grouped product has engine and body parts  which both are grouped products with a lot of associated products. A user should be able to click on corresponding tab which should load engine product pictures and body product pictures depending on which tab he has clicked. How can I add those 2 products in the backend, with a meaningful relation between those two products that can be used to identify the product in frontend?

Answer (score 0):

With the information you give, I would advise you to make a bundle product more than a grouped product. If the idea is that a customer can customize the product he orders, bundled products are definitely better.

To dynamically display things, you will need to use javascript.